# cannot save jasperreport into excel file only the webpage content is saved to the file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to save the Jasperreport into an excel file. But while we generate the excel file only the webpage content is saved to the excel file. The Jasper report content is not saved to the excel file.

```
public void generateXLSOutput(JasperPrint jasperPrint, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, JRException {
        String reportfilename = "SampleExcelReport" + ".xls";
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")            
        JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();                 
        exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
        exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
        exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
        exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, resp.getOutputStream());
        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + reportfilename);
        resp.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

        exporterXLS.exportReport();
}
```

Comment: Remove the deprecated code http://stackoverflow.com/a/33890101/5292302 and explain better what is actually happening, I can't understand "only the webpage content is saved to the excel file", which webpage content?, screen shot?

Comment: @Alex K : I am generating the excel file from a web page. The web page contains the options to generating the report in excel, PDF and Html format. I choose the option excel format and then press the generate button, The excel file will be generated. But the content of the excel file is the above html file content. That is the options PDF/Excel?HTMl and button name etc.

Comment: @Alex K : I used the code in your  comment "stackoverflow.com/a/33890101/5292302 " but same thing happens no chnage in the excel file content.

Comment: Check [this answer which deals with headers send too late](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520231/how-to-force-browser-to-download-file/6520353#6520353) just to make sure.